# Is there any mechanism to suggest "Help Center" edits?

Tags: support, help-center

The topic pretty much stands for itself.

Is there any way for users to suggest edits to "Help Center" topics? Those suggested edits can then be reviewed by moderators only.

If there is no auto mechanism in place, how does one suggest a edit? Via this very meta site?

Comment: Same as [privileges wiki edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Comment: Seems like this only relevant to meta. I do not see this on the same SO [page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Comment: Yes. We can suggest edits on Meta Privileges page only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no review queue or system like the privilege wiki edits for the help center.

If you'd like to suggest an edit to a page, or propose a new article, post your idea to any meta site. Make sure it's tagged [help-center-proposed](/questions/tagged/help-center-proposed). If it's a simple grammatical error or typo, someone on the staff will fix it. If you're proposing a substantive change, we'll wait for the community to weigh in and then make a decision on a case by case basis. If your change will affect all sites in the network, here (MSE) is the best place to post your idea; likewise, if it's content relevant only to one particular site, post to that site's meta.