# Update page about "Talk In Chat" privilege in Help Centers

Tags: discussion, help-center, help-center-proposed

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188838/is-there-any-mechanism-to-suggest-help-center-edits) says edits to the Help Center shall be posted in a meta, so here you go.

On the [Talk In Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) page, under **Where is chat?**, it says a link can be found in the "top left corner of the page". This should be top RIGHT corner :-) At least on the computers I have...

And this seems to be the same for the Help Center on all sites (at least 
the 4 I checked).

**Update**: On the main and meta sites, it's in the upper right corner, but in the chat, it's in the upper left corner, so the UI is different...

Comment: heh, probably needs to be changed in one place. And I guess that slipped through the 2017 top bar changes