# What's the difference between the help-center and help-center-proposed tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, help-center

I found out in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188838/is-there-any-mechanism-to-suggest-help-center-edits), that edits to the Help Center shall be posted in a meta. It also says "Make sure it's tagged [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center)".

While posting such a suggestion, I could see there are both a [help-center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/help-center/info) and a [help-center-proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/help-center-proposed/info) tag, but I can't really see the difference.

So can anyone clarify what the difference is and when to use one or the other? Or are they redundant?

To post in the meta, it also needs a "core" tag, so I have selected [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), since that seemed least "irrelevant" (it's not a bug, feature request or support either, just a small fix). So while talking about the help-center tags (for edit suggestions), I would also like to ask why it's necessary with an "extra" tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linked answer is older than the help-center-proposed tag and should presumably be updated.

According to the brief tag wikis, [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center) is for questions about the help center more generally, and [help-center-proposed](/questions/tagged/help-center-proposed) is specifically for proposed content.  On the former I see questions requesting changes (but without concrete suggestions), bug reports (like missing images), questions about the ordering of topics, design/layout, and search.

Comment: I agree that the linked answer should be updated, so I have done that, and waiting for someone to review it.

Comment: The tag wiki for the tag [tag:faq-update-request] (referring to the old `/faq` page) still says to use the [tag:help-center] tag.