# Is there a way to be notified of new or edited help articles in order to help to translate them?

Tags: support, help-center, translations, international-sites

Yesterday gbianchi posted on Meta Stack Overflow en Español [a post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3745/65) about how could we help translating a help article that looks to be new. The related help article was announced on an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315332/289691) posted on September '18 to [Could we have a Help Center page on disassociating posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239366/289691) which was posted four years ago.

People following the above Meta SE question could be noticed the new help article. I'm wondering if there are other means to be notified about new help articles in order the international sites community help to translate them from English to the international site corresponding language.

Currently the only version that is already translated is the ru.so. es.so, pt.so, ja.so and rus.se versions are in English at this time.

NOTE:

On Stack Overflow en Español we had [a post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3264/65) we were coordinating efforts to translate help articles in English to Spanish but currently we are using a GitHub repo.

Links to the corresponding instance for each international site

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question (already translated)
- https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

---

According to [Is there any mechanism to suggest "Help Center" edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188838/289691) community suggestions / requests to update help articles should use [help-center-proposed](/questions/tagged/help-center-proposed). At this time there are 11 questions using this tag but only one has [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: could that happen [in the terminal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317209/the-terminal-a-chat-room-for-international-site-users)

Comment: Didn't happen b/c the terminal is newer than the referred help article used to illustrate the concern (: But this question is about future new/edited help articles.

Comment: I think someone, like a worker on the site itself, should at least translate it once it's edited or replaced by a new one.

Comment: Good one! Also, we currently do not have a way to know if an article from the Help Center is updated, either, so international sites may have translations of outdated documents.

Comment: Possible related: [Improved Help Center - site-specific pages and site-specific edits to all pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279879/289691) (see the last part of the Jon Ericson's answer)

Comment: @Rubén This has been added to the queue for upcoming features.  It will be prioritized along with all other community requests.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know @JuanM

Comment: @JuanM [tag:status-planned] then?